# Undo a convolution involving an inverse Laplace transform and definite integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, absolute-value

While asking my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063862/inverse-laplace-transform-involving-an-laplace-transform-and-an-absolute-sine-fu) , I wanted to solve $(1)$ that is stated below this sentence:

$$\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1+\text{L}\cdot\text{C}_2\cdot\text{s}^2}\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[\left|\sin\left(\omega t+\theta\right)\right|\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Using the answer of [#msm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/350875/msm), I was able to get (using convolution theorem and where $*$ is the convolution of the two functions):

$$\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{L}\cdot\text{C}_2}}\cdot\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{L}\cdot\text{C}_2}}\cdot t\right)\right\}\space*\space\left|\sin\left(\omega t+\theta\right)\right|\tag2$$

> Now, to undo the convolution, I have to solve the integral (posted in red under this sentence):
>
> $$\color{red}{\mathcal{I}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{L}\cdot\text{C}_2}}\cdot\int_0^t\sin\left(\frac{t-\tau}{\sqrt{\text{L}\cdot\text{C}_2}}\right)\cdot\left|\sin\left(\omega\tau+\theta\right)\right|\space\text{d}\tau}\tag3$$

---

Where I was thinking of expanding function: $\left|\sin\left(\omega\tau+\theta\right)\right|$ into its $\cos$ Fourier series like this:

$$\mathcal{I}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{L}\cdot\text{C}_2}}\cdot\int_0^t\sin\left(\frac{t-\tau}{\sqrt{\text{L}\cdot\text{C}_2}}\right)\cdot\left\{\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{\text{n}\ge1}\frac{\cos\left(2\text{n}\left(\omega\tau+\theta\right)\right)}{4\text{n}^2-1}\right\}\space\text{d}\tau$$

Comment: One option is to try breaking up your integral like so
$$\int_0^t = \int_0^\pi + \int_\pi^{2\pi} + \cdots +\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}+\int_{k\pi}^t$$
then using the fact that $|sin(x)| = (-1)^j\sin(x)$ over the interval $[j\pi,(j+1)\pi]$ you have an alternating sum of integrals of products of sine functions. They can then be individually integrated using sine product identities.